# instance variable going out of scope

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an NSString which has been declared as property and being allocated and initialised in view did load as below:

```
NSString *textWithKey;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *textWithKey;
```

in .m i have

```
@synthesize textWithKey;
```

and in viewDidLoad i have

```
self.textWithKey=[[NSString alloc]init];
    self.textWithKey=@"";
```

Now somewhere in my code i am using

```
self.textWithKey=[self.textWithKey stringByAppendingString:text1];
```

it works fine untill another method is called which returns different values.
and from there on this perticularline is called again but debugger shows textWithKey out of scope.I have not released textWihKey any where.

Comment: First of all the `self.textWithKey=[[NSString alloc]init];` line is completely unnecessary because of the next line... As for your problem - can you post the "another method" code? In addition will help if you will go over all the places where you use `textWithKey` and post that lines too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's right. You did not release it. But you also didn't allocate it. ;-) At first you called `self.textWithKey = [[NSString alloc] init]`. Than you call `self.textWithKey = @""`. Because you use the setters for the property, the old assigned value is released every time. Try the following:

```
self.textWithKey = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
```

Because

```
self.textWithKey = @"";
```

is the same as

```
self.textWithKey = [NSString stringWithString:@""];
```

And there you don't allocate anything. ;-)

Comment: That's not true. both the `@""` shortcut and the `[NSString string...]` versions return autoreleased objects, already allocated. Since they're autoreleased, they don't need explicit releasing.

Comment: that was the case indeed.I tried your code and it works fine for me.Thanks

Comment: Yeah that's right Dan Ray. I said it the wrong way. You need to allocate memory. But you don't it by hand and you get an autoreleased string back. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Variables going out of scope are not the same as being released.